# PostgreSQL Query Using Crosstab

Tags: postgresql, crosstab

Now, I am leaning postgreSQL. In the study, I found crosstab in postgreSQL. I tried to apply this function to my customized table, but it dose not work. please help!!

This is my Table

```
 year | type     | count 
------+----------+----
 2015 | AS       |  6
 2015 | HY       |  6
 2015 | KR       |  6
 2015 | SE       |  6
 2016 | AS       |  2
 2016 | HY       |  2
 2016 | KR       |  2
 2016 | SE       |  2
 2017 | AS       |  1
 2017 | HY       |  1
 2017 | KR       |  1
 2017 | SE       |  1
 2018 | AS       |  2
 2018 | HY       |  2
 2018 | KR       |  2
 2018 | SE       |  2
```

I want to change this table like this

```
year |  AS  |  HY  |  KR  |  SE  |
----------------------------------
2015 |   6  |   6  |   6  |   6  |
2016 |   2  |   2  |   2  |   2  |
2017 |   1  |   1  |   1  |   1  |
2018 |   2  |   2  |   2  |   2  |
```

To make that table, I designed query using crosstab, but dose not work!

Please Let me know the query of this problem.

Comment: Please always check for formatting while posting the question. It can be seen below the input field. I’ve fixed it for you now. Also what kind of queries did you try that didn’t work?

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this without `Crosstab`, you can use [`Aggregate`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES) function.

Query :

```
select 
  year,
  max(counts) filter (where type = 'AS') as "AS",
  max(counts) filter (where type = 'HY') as "HY",
  max(counts) filter (where type = 'KR') as "KR",
  max(counts) filter (where type = 'SE') as "SE"
from
  tbl
group by
  year
order by 
  year asc
```

[*Demo <> DB Fiddle*](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=3a64ae27fa9fbc78769646f324dededc)

And if you are try learning `Crosstab` this answer are really great and explain really well about to do pivot use `Crosstab`.

- [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query)